# Object returns own property and preserves methods

Tags: javascript, object, getter

I have an object that wraps some data:

```
function Obj1() {
    var _foo = 'bar'
    this.obj2 = {
        'b': 'c'
    }
    this.method = function() {
        return _foo
    }
}
var obj1 = new Obj1()
```

Now when I call `console.log(obj1);` I want it to show me object `obj2` content. The trick is that I need to still be able to call `obj1.method` and get value of `_foo`. How do I do that if it's even possible?
My thought was that sth like getter will be suitable, but can't figure out where and how to assign one.

Comment: So why not `console.log(obj1.method())`?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. How to assign a getter? take a look at [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Ok, so you want to log `obj2`? `console.log(obj1.obj2)`

Comment: I'll try to explain it another way.
I want console.log(obj1) show same as console.log(obj1.obj2) AND in the same time console.log(obj1.method()) show '_foo' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you're trying to hide `method` property. To achieve this, use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Function will not be logged because `enumerable` property is `false` by default which prevents property from showing in `console.log` for example.

```js
function Obj1() {
  var _foo = 'bar'
  this.obj2 = {
    'b': 'c'
  }
    
  Object.defineProperty(this.obj2, 'method', {
    value: function() {
      return _foo;
    }
  });
  
  return this.obj2;
}


  
var obj1 = new Obj1()

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj1.method());
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly, you can use `prototype`

Example

```
function Obj1() {
    this.obj2 = {
        'b': 'c'
    }
}
Obj1.prototype.method = function() {
    return 'bar';
}

var obj1 = new Obj1();

//prints only properties
console.log(obj1);

//prints method result
console.log(obj1.method())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you calling `new Obj1()`. The result variable `var obj1` is a class object and not a function, for you to get the value of `obj2` you will have to call `obj1.obj2` in your console log. If you want obj1 to hold the value of obj2. Then use the following code

```
function Obj1() {
    var obj2 = {
       'b': 'c'
    }
    return this.obj2;
}
var obj1 = Obj1();
console.log(obj1);
```

This will give you the required result in the console log, but the object will no longer be a class object and will have only the value of obj2.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your original snippet a factory looks like a good option:

```
function factory() {
    var foo = 'bar';
    var props = { b: 'c'};
    var proto = {
        method: function() { return foo; }
    }; 
    var obj = Object.create(proto);
    Object.assign(obj, props);
    return obj;
}

var obj = factory();
console.log(obj); // {b: 'c'}
console.log(obj.method()) // 'foo'
```

You could even pass props as an argument to get a more flexible way of spawning objects with an "[unenumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)" method accessing private members.

Comment: That's great idea.
To clone you can use `Object.assign()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign ;)